# Sequentially execute asynchronous methods based on a variable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, q

I have an array of answers.

```
var answers = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes'];
```

I have to enter these answers in a web quiz where the questions pop up sequentially. I sense the questions using selenium driver.

I enter the answers using the following method.

```
var answerQuestion = function(driver, answer) {
    var defer = q.defer();

    var elementXPath = "//*[contains(@class, 'quizAnswer’)]";
    var delay = 2000;

    return driver.waintUntilVisible(elementXPath, delay).sendKeys(answer);
};
```

Now I want to execute the above method for every answer in the `answers` array sequentially since the next question won't show up until the current question is answered.

A simple `foreach` loop fails here.

```
function submitAnswers(driver) {
    answers.forEach(function(answer) {
        answerQuestion(driver, answer);
    });
}
```

So how to sequentially execute asynchronous methods based on a variable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first `answerQuestion` should be promising:

```
function answerQuestion(driver, answer) {
 var elementXPath = "//*[contains(@class, 'quizAnswer’)]";
 var delay = 2000;

 return driver.waintUntilVisible(elementXPath, delay).sendKeys(answer);
}
```

Then it is quite easy:

```
function submitAnswers(driver, position = 0) {
    if(position >= answers.length) return;

    return answerQuestion(answers[position]).then(function() {
      return submitAnswers(driver, position + 1);
    });
 }
```

Or if you can use `async` / `await`:

```
async function submitAnswers(driver, answers) {
  for(const answer of answers)
     await answerQuestion(answer);
 }
```

Comment: I cannot use async await since I don't have babel integrated in the build. And without that I still have to invoke `submitAnswers' using a loop. And the result will be same as before.

Comment: @Giridhar no, have a look at the second snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Since selenium functions returns promises, you will have to resolve then one after other in sequence.

For your case following should do the magic.

```js
var answerQuestion = function(driver, answer) {
    return function() {
       var defer = q.defer();
       var elementXPath = "//*[contains(@class, 'quizAnswer’)]";
       var delay = 2000;
    return driver.waintUntilVisible(elementXPath,delay).sendKeys(answer);
};

function submitAnswers(driver) {
    return answers.reduce((previous, answer) => {
                return previous.then(answerQuestion(driver, answer);
            }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a way finally. credit to [Dave Ceddia](https://daveceddia.com/waiting-for-promises-in-a-loop/)

```
var answers = ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes'];

var answerQuestion = function(driver, answer) {
    var elementXPath = "//*[contains(@class, 'quizAnswer’)]";
    return driver.waintUntilVisible(elementXPath, delay).sendKeys(answer);
};

function submitAnswers(driver) {

    var chain = q.when();

    answers.forEach(function(answer) {
        chain = chain.then(function() {
            return answerQuestion(driver, answer);
        });
    });
}
```